# How can I insert a text item (question) with multiple response fields (and descriptions) in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, formatting

I'm trying to create a survey/Google Form specifically to export data into an Excel sheet. This isn't very important because I can tweak the arrangement after the fact, but naturally I have a lot of data coming in.

Some of the questions will be things like:

> Starting with most recent, please describe any education or achievements you have received:

But will require guidelines for the response and inputs, such as "Diploma," "Institution," "Location," and "Year." Each of these will require their own response box, but will apply to the same question. For example:

[image: A sample of the question type I need]

I thought of doing Page/Header breaks between question "groups" and entering multiple text items per break so that at least each topic was organized, but the result is sloppy:

[image: What it looks like in Google Forms]

If at the very least there were a way to move the title and help text alongside the response boxes, or minimize most of the spacing, it would look so much better. Even this sample is barely tolerable because of the example/help/description text in gray type. However this wouldn't be very useful for necessary fields like "Please include your contact information" (Name, Address 1, Address 2, City, State, Zip, Phone, Email, etc.) which would be tiny fields that don't need a whole page. After entering most of the items in either of these formats, the survey would be 10+ pages of drudgery when it should really only be three (including the instructions/introduction page).

I'm not above script editing but unfortunately I have a novice education on the subject and am limited to mimicking samples or tweaking a source. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in May 2021, Google Forms continues to offer very basic form layout tools. Questions appear vertically one after the other, with each question title on top of the answer box.

To design your own form layout, you can rewrite the form as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) for sample code.

Another way to get a prettier form layout is to use a Google Forms add-on like [Formfacade](https://formfacade.com/website/features.html). Note that it is not a free tool but requires a subscription.