# create data validation (pulldown) from other spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

I have current spreadsheet (named as INPUT). In this INPUT , i have a sheet named USER. I share USER sheet to other users so they can write data on it (as editor). On cell A1 , i will use data validation /pulldown from other spreadsheet (named as DATA).

The data validation can't use data directly from other spreadheet so in the INPUT spreadsheet , i create a new sheet (named as DATAIMPORT) and use importrange() to import from DATA.

It works fine but  the DATAIMPORT sheet is visible to all my users. How if i want the hide the DATAIMPORT from my users?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [creating a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input? Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion and are thus easy to process with spreadsheet functions such as `query()` and `filter()`.

If the users need access to the spreadsheet for some reason, you can just protect and hide the `DATA` sheet to make it a bit more difficult to view.

To retain interactivity but take the data completely out of reach, you will need to create a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.