# Interactive sheet (by pull down menu selection). Can I embed on website where users use it in isolation (without effect each other in live view)

Tags: google-sheets

I created this sheet which displays 2 columns, where the values change, according to some pull down menu selections.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110pWSQX2Kc3WeDvWm4BVwxPdtq2y9wyh39P9wjPVeS8/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a way to allow multiple users use this at the same time?

Filtered views didn't work, as it's only able to isolate sorting views.

The dropdown selection actually changes the cell value, and it live updated across all views.  I'd like to use the dropdown menus without effecting each other's view of the sheet.

Or should I look into some other tools to embed this on my website?

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. The link returns "Page not found".

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets is built for sharing and collaboration, so it may not be the best tool when you do not want users to see each other's changes.

The usual way to do this sort of thing on top of a Google Sheet is to build a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that uses a spreadsheet as its back end.

See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.